# How do I replace using eval to call a class?

Tags: python

I know `eval` is bad, I'm pretty new to coding.

I'm using config parser to define motors that open output gates to divert parts

from my config file:

```
 [Motor]out1=["Screw", "board0.motor1"]
```

Code

```
    out1=json.loads(config['Motor']['out1'])
    board0 = MotorKit(address= int(config['Motor']['board0'], 16))
    def openMotor(m):
        eval(m).throttle = 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
        eval(m).throttle = 0.2
    
    def open_gate(part):
        if part == out1[0]:
            openMotor(out1[1])
    open_gate("screw")
```

How do I not use `eval`? but be able to set the attritbute `board0.motor1.throttle` in the `openMotor` function?

Comment: Honestly, this is why lists of things should be stored in lists, instead of variables called thing0, thing1, thing2, etc.  If they were lists, it would just be `board[i][j].throttle = 0.2`.  How much control do you have over that?

Comment: What is the value of out1[1]?

Comment: Use a list or dict of objects instead.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm using the adafruit motorkit library, unfortunatly I don't have any control over the MotorKit class.

Comment: @ankurbohra04 out1=["Screw", "board0.motor1"], so out1[1] should be board0.motor1

Comment: you could add link to `adafruit motorkit library` . If it is created in Python then you always can change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: you can use `if/else` like `if m == "board0.motor1": m = board0.motor1`. Or you can keep it as dictionary `{"board0.motor1":  board0.motor1}`

Comment: source code uses "hidden" function [_motor(motor_name, ...)](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MotorKit/blob/master/adafruit_motorkit.py#L70) to convert string name to object. And it uses `gettattr(class, variable_name`) - `gettattr(board0, "motor1")`

Comment: eventually you should use class `MotorKit` to create own class `class MyMotorKit(MotorKit)` with all metods to access motors using string `screw`